# Loop through C# lists

Tags: c#

I am stuck on C# exercise. This list logs battles between different teams and records scores each one got. This list below is part of the exercise, and it must be there. I need to determine the following:

1. How many points each team got (for example, in this code snippet Team C has 15 points in total).
2. Determine rankings: team that wins gets 5 ranking points for a win and 0 for the loss (for example, Team B has 5 ranking points because it won the first battle but lost the second one). The team with more points is the winner.
3. How can I check at the end the total points and ranking score for each team?

There must be a simple solution, but I am just not seeing something. Still can't figure out how to loop through C# lists well. Some possible solutions would be highly appreciated (please keep the code as simple as possible so I manage to understand it).

```
List<List<string>> battle = new List<List<string>>();
battle.Add(new List<string> { "Team A", "7", "Team B", "13" });
battle.Add(new List<string> { "Team C", "10", "Team B", "2" });
battle.Add(new List<string> { "Team D", "3", "Team C", "5" });
// ... and the list goes on like this
```

Comment: "There must be a simple solution" - what makes you believe this? You need to define classes for each team and for each battle. That is the proper way of dealing with this problem. In C# your job is to define data structures and the logic behind them. The code snippet above holds all the data as a bag of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a data structures problem, so it all boils down to traversing the list and parsing out the values into a relevant data structure that can 1) accumulate the scores for each team, and 2) be sorted to give each team a rank.

The below example is one way to achieve this task. Note that the `Team` class implements the `IComparable` interface, which tells `List<Team>` how to order teams by the number of points that they hold. See [docs on the `CompareTo(...)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=net-5.0#System_IComparable_CompareTo_System_Object_), [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-5.0), and [`List<T>.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort) for more details.

```
public class Team {
   public string Name { get; init; }
   public int Points { get; private set; }
   
   public Team(string name) {
       Name = name;
       Points = 0;
   }

   public void RecordBattle(List<string> battle) : IComparable {
       if (battle.Count != 4) {
           throw new ArgumentException("Battle list must have four entries");
       }

       if (battle[0].Equals(Name)) {
           Points += int.Parse(battle[1]);
       } else if (battle[2].Equals(Name)) {
           Points += int.Parse(battle[3]);
       } else {
           throw new ArgumentException($"This team is not represented in this battle. Expected '{Name}', got '{battle[0]}' and '{battle[2]}'");
       }
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Team otherTeam = obj as Team;
        if (otherTeam != null) {
            return Points - otherTeam.Points;
        } else {
           throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Team");
        }
    }
}

public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        List<List<string>> battle = new List<List<string>>();
        battle.Add(new List<string> { "Team A", "7", "Team B", "13" });
        battle.Add(new List<string> { "Team C", "10", "Team B", "2" });
        battle.Add(new List<string> { "Team D", "3", "Team C", "5" });
        
        Dictionary<string, Team> teamsDict = new();
        List<Team> teamsList = new();
        
        // tally up points
        foreach (List<string> b in battle) {
            Team t;
            if (teamsDict.HasKey(b[0])) {
                t = teamsDict[b[0]];
            } else {
                t = new Team(b[0]);
                teamsList.add(t);
                teamsDict[b[0]] = t;
            }
            t.RecordBattle(b);
            if (teamsDict.HasKey(b[2])) {
                t = teamsDict[b[2]];
            } else {
                t = new Team(b[2]);
                teamsList.add(t);
                teamsDict[b[2]] = t;
            }
            t.RecordBattle(b);
        }

        // print out team points by rank (in order of most to fewest points)
        Console.WriteLine("Scores:");
        foreach (Team t in teamsList.OrderByDescending()) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{t.Name}: {t.Points}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To rank the teams and produce output like:

```
Team B has 15 points.
Team C has 15 points.
Team A has 7 points.
Team D has 3 points.
```

use `OrderByDescending()` and use each teams points for the ordering.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Team a = new Team("A");
        Team b = new Team("B");
        Team c = new Team("C");
        Team d = new Team("D");

        List<Battle> battles = new List<Battle>()
        {
            new Battle(a, 7, b, 13),
            new Battle(c, 10, b, 2),
            new Battle(d, 3, c, 5),
        };

        List<Team> teams = new List<Team>() { a, b, c, d };

        foreach (var team in teams.OrderByDescending( (t)=>t.Points) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Team {team.Name} has {team.Points} points.");
        }
    }
```

with supporting classes

```
public class Team
{
    public Team(string name)
    {
        Name=name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public int Points { get; set; } = 0;
}

public class Battle
{
    public Battle(Team a, int scoreA, Team b, int scoreB)
    {
        A=a;
        B=b;
        A.Points += scoreA;
        B.Points += scoreB;
    }

    public Team A { get; }
    public Team B { get; }
}
```